# Visual Basic 6 dealing with one string variable with so many charecters

Tags: vb6

I have a vb6 application that prints string to a text file. my string is very huge. Althogh my application works, Does doing such thing is logical? I mean something like bad use of memory or something else? and if i'm in wrong way what do you recommend?

My code is something like that
  Print #1, "THE BIG BIG STRING"

Comment: Is this for logging purposes? Also, how big are we talking?

Comment: @SpectralGhost: Bassically i want to create an  html file on fly. That file has 3 part. Part one and Part  three are two predetermined and big strings. and Part two will generate from a database.

Comment: part one has 1500 characters and part 3 has 6750

Comment: that isn't big. I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as all the data can be contained in the string without producing memory errors, it should be. However, if you are concatenating several values together to form your big string, you could just write them to the file individually.

I.e., turn this:

```
bigString = bigString & data1
bigString = bigString & data2
bigString = bigString & data3
```

To this:

```
Print #1, data1
Print #1, data2
Print #1, data3
```